# Log files randomly stops writing to log files

Tags: debian, logging, logrotate

I'm currently running Debian 10.1 x64
The problem started pretty much right after setting up the server.

Every now and then it seems like my system stops writing to the log files. If I check `/var/log` I can see that most of the logs are at a size of 0. If I restart the server, everything is back to normal and the server is using all the log files. Looking at the date, it seems that all these empty log files are created at the same date/time (right now at Nov  4 00:00) so I'm assuming it might be caused by logrotate but all the rotated logs have different times and are sometimes hours away from the creation date of the new files which also looks a bit weird. I didn't change anything in the logrotate config and I cant find any relevant information in any of the log files that could help with that problem.
Does anyone here know about a problem like that and how to solve it without restarting the server whenever that happens?

**Edit:** I was looking more at the problem to figure out whats going on and I noticed that it is indeed logrotate that creates the new logfiles but the system doesn't stop writing logs as I thought. It seems that after the logrotate the system is writing to `*.log.1` so the old log, instead of the newly created one. I never saw that happen before, is something wrong with my system or is that new on Debian 10? Is there any way to change that?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like [bug 900586](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=900586) ("systemd Service File Update Breaks logrotate").

Check for any files in `/etc/logrotate.d` that contain `invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate` and change it to `/usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a typical behavior, I have a computer with Debian 10 fresh install and this does not happen there. The reason this happens is usually that there are processes that have the log files open (that is a file descriptor is open to the file) and when `logrotate` rotates the files the file descriptor does not get updated and the processes continue to write to the old logfile. Why this is happening to normal log files like `syslog`, `auth.log` and such I have no idea.

A query to the Debian user mail list might be a good idea, you might get more knowledgable answers there. If that fails then file a bug report against `logrotate` and the package maintainers will have a look at the situation.

Comment: The only process that is active on the old logs is rsyslogd which if I understand it correctly is the only process that even creates all the different files? I'll look into the debian user mail list and see if I can gather some more informations to create a bugreport.

Comment: And check that the configuration files in /etc/logrotate.d have the required "post rotate" directives, particularly the "invoke-rc.d <service> reload" part...

Comment: @wazoox I do see the "postrotate" and "rsyslog rotate" commands but if i execute `invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate` by hand I get `[FAIL] Closing open files: rsyslogd failed!`. Is that normal if I execute it by hand or is that what causes the problem?

Comment: That is not normal no. Why this fail is happening is hard to say but running `strace` on it (`strace invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate`) might shed some light on it if you know how to read the output from strace.

Comment: So there is an outstanding [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=720096) about this issue, but another [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=865276) points to a wrong PID file, make sure that `/var/run/rsyslogd` exists, if only `/var/run/rsyslog` (without a `d ` in the end) exists then that could be the problem just like the latter bug talks about, but that one should be fixed.

Comment: @ojs I don't have either of them in /var/run ?

Comment: If rsyslogd is running, you definitely should have a /var/run/rsyslogd file...